# Can I check a std::condition_variable without a timeout?

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

I would like to use a std::condition_variable as an exit condition for a method called on a thread. I envision that it will be used like this:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable exit_condition;

void func() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    while (exit_condition.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(0)) == std::cv_status::timeout)
        // Do something
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(func);

    // Do something

    exit_condition.notify_one();
    t.join();
}
```

However it seems that with a zero timeout, the return value of `wait_for` is always `std::cv_status::timeout`.

If I were to write `func` using the Windows API, I would write it like this:

```
HANDLE exit_condition;
void func() {
    while (WaitForSingleObject(exit_condition, 0) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        // Do something
}
```

Note that I can write `func` with a small timeout and it will exit.

```
void func() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        while (exit_condition.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(10)) == std::cv_status::timeout)
            // Do something
    }
```

I'm a bit concerned that under some conditions it will not exit though.

So, can I check a std::condition_variable without a timeout in some way that will guarantee the return value of the `wait_for` method will be `std::cv_status::no_timeout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't actually need the timeout, you can get similar functionality without it by calling `wait()` instead of `wait_for()`.

If the only purpose of all this is to have one thread tell the other one when to stop running, a typical thing to do is to check an atomic bool at the top of the loop (`while (runnable)`) and toggle it from the other thread when you want the loop to exit.

Comment: Notice that a `wait` call might still return spuriously if you don't specify a predicate. So if you want to use it to block a function from exiting, you either need to give the predicate or loop on the wait and check the exit condition. This ties in with @chill's answer: A condition variable alone is useless, you also need to store the state of the condition itself somewhere.

Comment: The atomic bool is a (lock-free) [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag), requiring the use of `test_and_set`.

Comment: @DyP: thanks for the link.  The old-school way was/is to use `volatile bool`.  I didn't write that in my answer for fear of a hundred C++ experts coming to say that it is improper, but I guess it's worth mentioning here because it's in common usage.

Comment: Ad `volatile bool`: Well at least for MSVC, which provides memory order guarantees for `volatile` (unlike other implementations, and only when not specifying certain compiler flags).

Comment: @ComicSansMS I'm curious about how `wait` without a predicate could return spuriously. Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of calling it? Can you provide some more details about this case?

Comment: @JoshPeterson This is afaik a limitation of architectures that use [load-linked/store-conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) for atomic access: You might run into a situation where you are not sure if the condition variable was notified or not, so you have to wake the thread up to avoid missing it. In this case the `wait` either checks the predicate itself or gives control to the user so he can check it. This should not happen on architectures that use atomic compare-and-swap instructions like x86, but you need to be aware of it when writing portable code.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: Is there a portable way to determine if the `wait` returned due to a `notify_one` or `notify_all` call then? I don't see anything else on the `std::condition_variable` interface.

Comment: @JoshPeterson No. That's pretty much the whole point: If you wake up, the only way to determine if it was a legit or a spurious wakeup is by checking the condition predicate. It sounds weird at first, but it actually makes sense if you realize that the condition variable is only meant to be used together with an actual condition that is represented by other data in the program.

Comment: ...and it seems that the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows for spurious wakeups as well. So I have to revise my earlier statement, the problem can also occur on x86.

Comment: The usual case of spurious wakeup is when a thread changes the predicate, signals the condition variable, unlocks the mutex, but before the thread, which waits on the condition is able to re-acquire the lock, another thread comes, takes the lock and modifies the predicate in a way that causes the woken up thread to need to wait again.

Comment: @chill Yes, but that's a situation that can be avoided by careful implementation. The much more tricky case is if you get woken up even though no one ever called notify, which can also happen.

Comment: @DyP - `std::atomic<bool>` is **not** `std::atomic_flag`. It has the full atomic interface.

Comment: @ComicSansMS, I don't see how this is possible to avoid, no matter how "careful" is the implementation. Would you suggest a possible approach?

Comment: @chill It's mainly a question of serializing your consumers. For example, if all consumers are launched beforehand and you only consume a single resource per wakeup, you will get such a system. In some cases this is desirable, especially if you need to care about fairness. But then on the other hand such a system usually performs less efficient than one that allows 'stolen wakeups'.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes; but the "atomic bool" (of John's answer) here can be implemented as a `std::atomic_flag`, at least as far as I see. And that is guaranteed to be lock-free.

Comment: Thanks all for the discussion. I think a useful guideline is to avoid calling the `wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock)` overload on `std::condition_variable`. Instead, the `wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock, Predicate pred)` overload should always be called, and the predicate should be checked after `wait` returns.

Comment: In the standard, 3.50.1[#10] indeed indicates that `wait` may return spuriously.

Answer (score 0):

Condition variables are not event objects. In particular, they don't have memory.

Set an explicit exit flag. And you actually do polling, so there's no need for any condition variables (merits of polling discussion aside).

```
bool exit_request = false;
std::mutex m;

void func() {
    while (true) {
        {
           std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
           if (exit_request)
               return;
        }
        do_something();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(func);

    // Do something

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        exit_request = true;
    }
    t.join();
}
```

PS. And, yeah, as said above, a simple atomic flags will do in this case.

Comment: In fact, I think it is necessary to use an `std::atomic<bool>` in this case. I believe that there is a chance change to the `bool` will not be seen by func, if, for instance, it is executed on a different processor. Or does the `lock()` call on the `std::mutex` guarantee that caches are consistent across all processors?

Comment: Yes, definitely, check 1.10[#5]

Comment: @JoshPeterson - the mutex that the condition variable uses provides synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the answers and the various discussion topics, I wanted to pull things together in one answer.

The answer to my original question is yes, you can check a std::condition_variable without a timeout, but it must be one of the `wait` overloads which accepts a predicate.

First, it seems that a `std:condition_variable` may not be the best tool to signal a thread to exit . A `std::mutex` and a shared `bool` or an `std::atomic<bool>` or `std::atomic_flag` work better.

If you do plan to use  `std::condition_variable` as I proposed in the question, be aware of the possibility of a *spurious wake*. According to 3.50.1[#10] in the C++11 standard, a call to `wait`, `wait_for`, or `wait_until` may return without a call to `notify_one`, `notify_all`, or the  predicate returning true.

This implies two guidelines:

- Any code after `wait` returns must explicitly check the return value of the predicate.
- None of the `wait` methods which do not accept a predicate should be called.

The following code accomplishes the goal of the original code in my answer, but does so safely.

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable exit_condition;
bool should_exit;

void func() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    while (!exit_condition.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(0), []{return should_exit;})) {
        if (should_exit)
            break;
        // Do something
    }
}

int main() {
    should_exit = false;
    std::thread t(func);

    // Do something

    should_exit  = true;
    exit_condition.notify_one();
    t.join();
}
```